# Moshi parse nested objects with duplicate fields

Tags: android, json, retrofit, moshi

I have the following JSON object which is an object containing many objects

```
{
  "people": {
    "john": {
      "age": "25",
      "location": "Japan",
      "favColor": "green"
    },
    "Bill": {
      "age": "65",
      "location": "Canada",
      "favColor": "red"
    },
    "Ann": {
      "age": "42",
      "location": "USA",
      "favColor": "blue"
    },
    "Frank": {
      "age": "45",
      "location": "USA",
      "favColor": "violet"
    }
  }
}
```

How would I go about parsing this into a list? As the amount of objects could grow quite large, I don't want to deal with a colossal amount of nested data.

Comment: I think it's much easier if you can add a header in your names like "name": "john" etc. On that parsing is much easier.

Comment: @GoldwynDator I don't have control over the response.

Comment: Have you tried to parse it? Can you provide code?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Assuming our JSON structure is exactly as I've posted and we have a `Person` class with `age` `location` and `favColor` fields, we need to create a moshi adapter that will take our JSON and return a list. We would also use a delegate to parse each object to our Person class. It would look something like this:

```
class PersonListAdapter {

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader, delegate: JsonAdapter<Person>): List<Person> {
        val list = ArrayList<Person>()

        reader.beginObject()
        reader.skipName()
        reader.beginObject()
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.skipName()
            delegate.fromJson(reader)?.let { list.add(it) }
        }
        reader.endObject()
        reader.endObject()
        return list
    }
}
```